# how to solve: f(n) = f(n-1) + 3*f(n-2) + 3*f(n-3) + f(n-4)

Tags: python, c++, algorithm

How can I solve

```
f(n) = f(n-1) + 3*f(n-2) + 3*f(n-3) + f(n-4) maximum value of n = 10^18 minimum is 1
initial conditions are
f(1) = 1
f(2) = 3
f(3) = 3
f(4) = 1
```

when `f(n)` can be large? `print f(n) modulus 10000007`

My try to this problem was as follows
(may be wrong in using the modulo)

```
1st test case:
3
2
5
9

output:
3
20
695
(working fine)

2nd tst case:
3
1554894
5959595
2562651

output:
7505501
9551828
6592801
(working fine)
```

but for larger number the program fails; why?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
T = int(raw_input())
def fib_iter(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    if n == 2:
        return 3
    if n == 3:
        return 3
    if n == 4:
        return 1   
    prev1, prev2, prev3, prev4 = 1, 3, 3, 1

    i = 5
    while i < n+1:
        curr = (prev1%10000007 + 3*prev2%10000007 + 3*prev3%10000007 + prev4%10000007)%10000007
        prev1, prev2, prev3, prev4 = prev2%10000007, prev3%10000007, prev4%10000007, curr%10000007
        i = i + 1
    return curr%10000007

for t in xrange(T):
    n = int(raw_input())
    print fib_iter(n)
```

Comment: Have you considered looking at the google codejam submitted solutions?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is an "I can haz teh codez plz" question

Comment: http://ideone.com/qHudOC

Comment: i have embedded the link of my current program ... program is taking long time during execution when input is large (say 10000000) and giving wrong ans.. but giving wrong ans also

Comment: @NeilKirk: Debashish is the him that's doing the learning.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Oops time for bed

Comment: please help ! :) ... i don't know how to to handle very large number..  at least give me some tutorial reference or logic

Comment: I suggest you write a new question containing your code and stating the specific problem you are having. Simply asking how to code it and nothing else will not get a helpful answer.

Comment: You don't state the specific problem. You need to explain that the code you have written takes a long time to execute with certain inputs and how it can be improved. It's not clear if it is giving the wrong answer for small inputs. If so, I would focus on that first.

Comment: @NeilKirk sorry i don't have that much of experience ..if I would have ... i would not post it here ... to keep it simple .. the problem is here ... need to solve this

Comment: First you can use a matrix to present the recursion, then you can use something like fast matrix pow to solve it. Refer to this http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=features&d2=010408

Comment: also check: http://goo.gl/A3uLSo

Comment: How exactly does your code fail?

Comment: for n = 15616511848   output should be = 5370032 but my output is = 5428387 ..

Comment: @Debashish - I updated my answer below which includes a correction to your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the matrix method the execution becomes very fast and reliable. 
http://x-perienceo.blogspot.in/

Answer (score 3):

Read [this book](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html), then solve it by hand.

**EDIT:** as I was asked to provide more details: With "solving", I meant to derive an explicit formula which directly gives you the coefficient f(n) [such that there is no recursion necessary]. For the normal Fibonacci series, such is given by the Binet formula. Following the recipe in the linked book, you can do it with the following steps:

1. Derive the generating function of the n-th coefficient. Basically, this is done by considering a function which has a power series expansion in terms of the sought coefficients f(n), and combining the several terms into one function.
2. Given the generating function, derive the expansion coefficient standing in front of the monomial x^n. As the generating function you specified contains at most fourth order polynomials, this can even be done analytically.

If there were some math mode here I would provide more mathematical details, and with some luck also the solution. But just try it like this, it is easy and the book is well readable.

Comment: While the book recommendation doesn't seem very fit for this site, it does seem like it is something solvable by math only

Answer (score 1):

update - try changing those two lines in the loop to:

```
    curr = (prev1 + 3*prev2 + 3*prev3 + prev4)%10000007
    prev1, prev2, prev3, prev4 = curr, prev1, prev2, prev3
```

With modulus 10000007, n = 15616511848, you should get 5370032 as you mentioned. Note that 10000007 = 941 x 10627 and is not prime. I'm not sure why it was chosen. Typically these type of problems use 1000000007 (7 + 10^9) which is a prime number.

Speeding up this algorithm is more of a math problem than a programming problem. The matrix form for this is:

```
       |  1  3  3  1 |
   a = |  1  0  0  0 |
       |  0  1  0  0 |
       |  0  0  1  0 |

       |  1 |
x[4] = |  3 |
       |  3 |
       |  1 |

x[i+1] = a x[i]

x[i+j] = a^j x[i]
```

Repeated squaring can be used to speed up calculating a^j .

In case you're curious x[0] through x[4] without the modulus. For the modulus, add the modulus (10000007) to the negative numbers:

```
x[0] =  -14,  39, -73, 117
x[1] =    1, -14,  39, -73
x[2] =    3,   1, -14,  39
x[3] =    3,   3,   1, -14
x[4] =    1,   3,   3,   1
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a more elaborate answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26281100/461597).

1. It is important to know that 1000007 is **prime**. Therefore you can use Euler's Theorem. Euler's Theorem states that for a prime number p, `a**x % p == a**y % p` (Python notation) if `x % (p-1) == y % (p-1)`.
2. Try to find a matrix notation to compute f(n) for any n without first recursively having to compute f(n-1) and so on. Then use exponentiation by squaring to compute it (up to your modulo as stated in 1. above).

Comment: In this case, 10000007 is being used, and it's not prime, so Euler's Theorem doesn't apply, but it's not needed for this problem, even when squaring a matrix.

Comment: thank you !! i have solved that problem using matrix method ..which is very fast !!! http://x-perienceo.blogspot.in/